# Not Able to start Activity from a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to navigate to a new activity from a fragment which is tied to another activity(for eg MainActivity).

When I try to do the following in OnClick of a button in the fragment:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            //Fragment fragment = null;
            //fragment = new MakeOfferFragment(post.getUniqueId());
            CommonResources.flowForOffers = "";

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(),NewActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
}
```

it just opens up the same activity(MainActivity) with the first fragment which was added initially. Even the onCreate of the NewActivity is not getting called

It should navigate me to the new Activity.

Manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".NewActivity "
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAKEOFFER" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>




   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Also the new activity holds a FragmentTabHost.

Comment: Try to use `getActivity().startActivity(i); `

Comment: @random tried that. But, it doesn't help.

Comment: Try to communicate to another activity via `fragment`'s associated `activity`. Check more on this here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: But what is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Ideally it should work. Might be able to comment if you put additional code for your fragment and activities.

Comment: @pagalpanda there shouldn't be anything wrong with this code. I use similar code daily without issues, so the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: @poss the NewActivity is extending MainActivity. Do you think that is causing the problem?

Comment: please add the part of the AndroidManifest were both activities are defined. 
Also is not recommended to start activity directly from a fragment. cleaner to go from the Activity that includes the relevant fragment.

Comment: Please see the edits. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does it work ?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExampleActivity.class);
getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```